# SQL Decimal equivalent in tablueau?

Tags: java, tableau-api

I have a SQL server table having column of type decimal(10,5) which should be used in creating a tableau extract, So while creating extract

```
if(colType.startsWith("decimal")){
                    tableDef.addColumn(colName, Type.CHAR_STRING);// what is the type i should use here?
                }

row.setInteger(j, (int) rowData.get(j));//what is the method to set a decimal value?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Tableau just has Number as the data type, at least that's all that I see in the UI.

The precision (in your case 5) can be set in display by selecting 'Format' and in calculations using ROUND(num,precision).